# How to set the font style back again?

Tags: fonts

Normally I just sue T1-fontenc and all is done. But for my frontpage I used FiraSans. Now I don't know how to, for the rest of the document, get back to the original font?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\renewcommand*\oldstylenums[1]{{\firaoldstyle #1}}
\begin{document}
THIS IS THE FRONT PAGE
\pagebreak
HERE I WANT A TEXT WITHOUT SANS-SERIF
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Your example does not produce sans-serif, old-style nums, or any nums for that matter.

Comment: Does `\normalfont` help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't invoke the `sfdefault` option of `FiraSans` package.  Just invoke `\sffamily` when you want that sans style, and `\rmfamily` when you are done.

If you need, additionally, to ditch FiraSans altogether after the front page and restore the, for example, Computer Modern sans font, just issue `\renewcommand\sfdefault{cmss}` and `cmss` will become the new sans font.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\renewcommand*\oldstylenums[1]{{\firaoldstyle #1}}
 %% option 'sfdefault' activates Fira Sans as the default text font 
\usepackage{FiraSans}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\begin{document}
\sffamily THIS IS THE FRONT PAGE 123456789

\rmfamily HERE I WANT A TEXT WITHOUT SANS-SERIF 123456789

\renewcommand\sfdefault{cmss}

\sffamily FiraSans gone cmss restored 123456789

\end{document}
```

[image]